# How to write a hashtable<string, string > in to text file,java?

Tags: java, hashtable

I have hastable
htmlcontent  is html string of urlstring .
I want to write hastable into a .text file .

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For text representation, I would recommend picking a few characters that are very unlikely to occur in your strings, then outputting a CSV format file with those characters as separators, quotes, terminators, and escapes.  Essentially, each row (as designated by the terminator, since otherwise there might be line-ending characters in either string) would have as the first CSV "field" the key of an entry in the hashtable, as the second field, the value for it.

A simpler approach along the same lines would be to designate one arbitrary character, say the backslash `\`, as the escape character.  You'll have to double up backslashes when they occur in either string, and express in escape-form the tab (`\t`) and line-end (`'\n`); then you can use a real (not escape-sequence) tab character as the field separator between the two fields (key and value), and a real (not escape-sequence) line-end at the end of each row.

Answer (score 3):

How about one row for each entry, and two strings separated by a comma?  Sort of like:

```
"key1","value1"
"key2","value2"
...
"keyn","valuen"
```

keep the quotes and you can write out keys that refer to null entries too, like

```
"key", null
```

To actually produce the table, you might want to use code similar to:

```
public void write(OutputStreamWriter out, HashTable<String, String> table)
throws IOException {
  String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
  for (String key: table.keySet()) {
    out.write("\"");
    out.write(key);
    out.write("\",\"");
    out.write(String.valueOf(table.get(key)));
    out.write("\"");
    out.write(eol);
  }
  out.flush();
}
```

Comment: This is a approuch for print a hastable, but i mean write hashtable into txt file 
 i use 

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(resultOutputFile)); 
writer.write(googleHashTableResult);

but it hava an error :erro The method write(int) in the type BufferedWriter is not applicable for the arguments

Comment: FileWriter is a subclass of OutputStreamWriter.  BufferedWriter isn't.  Don't pass in a BufferedWriter, pass in a FileWriter.  If that isn't what you want, then adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I have approuch like you say !

Some thing like that 

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        for(Entry<String, String> obj: googleHashTableResult.entrySet()) {
         writer.write(obj.getKey()); 
         writer.write(newline);
         writer.write(obj.getValue());
        }
        writer.close();
        buffer.close();

Answer (score 3):

For the I/O part, you can use a [`new PrintWriter(new File(filename))`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.File%29). Just call the `println` methods like you would `System.out`, and don't forget to `close()` it afterward. Make sure you handle any `IOException` gracefully.

If you have a specific format, you'd have to explain it, but otherwise a simple `for-each` loop on the [`Hashtable.entrySet()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#entrySet%28%29) is all you need to iterate through the entries of the `Hashtable`.

By the way, if you don't need the `synchronized` feature, a [`HashMap<String,String>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) would probably be better than a `Hashtable`.

#### Related questions

- [Java io ugly try-finally block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699209/java-io-ugly-try-finally-block)
- [Java hashmap vs hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/java-hashmap-vs-hashtable)
- [Iterate Over Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/iterate-over-map)

---

Here's a simple example of putting things together, but omitting a robust `IOException` handling for clarity, and using a simple format:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class HashMapText {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("map.txt"));

        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("1111", "One");
        map.put("2222", "Two");
        map.put(null, null);

        for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            out.println(entry.getKey() + "\t=>\t" + entry.getValue());
        }

        out.close();
    }
}
```

Running this on my machine generates a `map.txt` containing three lines:

```
null    =>  null
2222    =>  Two
1111    =>  One
```

As a bonus, you can use the first declaration and initialization of `out`, and print the same to standard output instead of a text file.

#### See also

- [Difference between java.io.PrintWriter and java.io.BufferedWriter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747040/difference-between-java-io-printwriter-and-java-io-bufferedwriter)
- [`java.io.PrintWriter` API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

  > Methods in this class never throw I/O exceptions, although some of its constructors may. The client may inquire as to whether any errors have occurred by invoking `checkError()`.

Comment: This will fail on a key that refers to a null entry with a NullPointerException.  Remember, Maps have keys that refer to entries which may be null.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Must be suffering from coding too defensively, which typically isn't a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
class FileWrite 
{
   public static void main(String args[])
  {
    HashTable table = //get the table
    try{
        // Create file 
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.txt"));
        writer.write(table.toString());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
      out.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It have an erro The method write(int) in the type BufferedWriter is not applicable for the arguments (Hashtable<String,String>)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
public static void save(String filename, Map<String, String> hashtable) throws IOException {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.putAll(hashtable);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    try {
       prop.store(fos, prop);
    } finally {
       fos.close();
    }
}
```

This stores the hashtable (or any Map) as a properties file. You can use the Properties class to load the data back in again.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have any requirements to the file format, I would not create a custom one. Just use something standard. I would recommend use json for that!

Alternatives include xml and csv but I think that json is the best option here. Csv doesn't handle complex types like having a list in one of the keys of your map and xml can be quite complex to encode/decode.

Using [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple) as example:

```
String serialized = JSONValue.toJSONString(yourMap);
```

and then just save the string to your file (what is not specific of your domain either using Apache Commons IO):

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(yourFilePath), serialized);
```

To read the file:

```
Map map = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(yourFilePath));
```

You can use other json library as well but I think this one fits your need.

Comment: Ok thanks your reply. I have a question about jonson array. When i use google api to query a string and get the result. 
String serialized = JSONValue.toJSONString(yourMap);
 
But when i show the result by Jeditor, it can't dislay the uicode (VietNamese ) but yahoo seach reult can .
Show what is the encode of result of google seachengine ? and how can i dislay the result when it is vietnamese ?

Comment: tiendv,

Sorry about the late answer. This is another question, you should one answer here and open a different question for this one. Cheers,