# Outputting a String into a file, without clearing the file

Tags: java

I've been working on sort of "logging" to text file using BufferedWriter and I came across a problem:

I run the following code.. fairly basic..

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path+fileName));
String str = "blabla";
out.write(str);
out.close();
```

and the next thing I know is that the entire file that had couple of lines of text has been cleared and only 'blabla' is there.

What class should I use to make it add a new line, with the text 'blabla', without having to get the entire file text to a string and adding it to 'str' before 'blabla'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What class should I use to make it add a new line, with the text 'blabla', without having to get the entire file text to a string and adding it to 'str' before 'blabla'?

You're using the right classes (well, maybe - see below) - you just didn't check the construction options. You want the [`FileWriter(String, boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) constructor overload, where the second parameter determines whether or not to append to the existing file.

However:

- I'd recommend against `FileWriter` in general anyway, as you can't specify the encoding. Annoying as it is, it's better to use `FileOutputStream` and wrap it in an `OutputStreamWriter` with the right encoding.
- Rather than using `path + fileName` to combine a directory and a filename, use `File`:

  ```
  new File(path, fileName);
  ```

  That lets the core libraries deal with different directory separators etc.
- Make sure you close your output using a `finally` block (so that you clean up even if an exception is thrown), or a "try-with-resources" block if you're using Java 7.

So putting it all together, I'd use:

```
String encoding = "UTF-8"; // Or use a Charset
File file = new File(path, fileName);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, true), encoding));
try {
   out.write(...);
} finally {
   out.close()'
}
```

Comment: Snap, never noticed it had another constructor.
I'll take those comments into my mind, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `FileWriter(filename, append)`  where append is true.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outfilename", true)));
    out.println("the text");
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    //oh noes!
}
```

The above should work: [Source Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

Comment: I'd avoid `PrintWriter` if possible... do you *really* want exceptions to be silently swallowed?

Comment: Why avoid it? You can invoke 'checkErrors()' if needed. Although you're correct, it's not strictly necessary and if there's concern it can simply be removed.

Comment: If you're going to call `checkErrors()`, why bother using `PrintWriter` at all? What is the *benefit* of using `PrintWriter`? All it buys you (that you should actually *want*) is a convenient way of writing a new-line. I'd rather not forsake "on-by-default" exceptions just for that.

Comment: That's where the **if needed** comes in from my last comment. It's a [convenience class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765978/why-need-printwriter), if he's doing simple logging you don't always want or need exceptions to be thrown. If he is, however, worried about it, then removing it is the best choice, you're right.