# How to ensure prompt output to the file with BufferedWriter?

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I am writing to a text file in a while loop:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter("...");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader("...");

while((line = reader.readline()) != null){
    ....
    writer.write(line + "\n");
}

reader.close();
writer.close();
```

This code doesn't write the line to the file as soon as each line is processed. I want the line to be written into the file in each iteration. How to achieve that?

Comment: Maybe `flush` it? But why use `BufferedWriter` if you do not want it `Buffered`?

Comment: Why are you using a buffered writer then? If you don't want to buffer the output, just use a FileWriter

Comment: What exactly mean by "buffered" and when to use it compared to FileWriter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `writer(line + "\n");` is not a method that exists. `writer` is the name of the BufferedWriter object. You need to add the method call to print your output with `writer.println("...");`
2. You should surround your code in a try-catch clause when working with IO to prevent IOExceptions
3. A simpler way to do this would be with a PrintWriter instead of a BufferedWriter.

Comment: In a while loop, BufferedWriter would be more efficient? Or not?

Comment: The input should still be a BufferedReader but the output does nothing differently because of a while loop

Comment: Isn't the case that the BufferedWriter accumulates data in multiple iterations and saves a lot of writing operations? So you mean in a typical while loop, BufferedWriter shouldn't be used?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747040/difference-between-java-io-printwriter-and-java-io-bufferedwriter

Comment: According to the link, BuffereWriter is still more efficient but PrinterWriter provides more methods? BufferedWriter saves disk writing in a while loop?

Comment: Unless you're seriously trying to save memory, in general I would go with PrintWriter

Comment: My writer wraps in 'BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName)))', how is it compared to "PrintWriter out
   = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("foo.out")));"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179866/discussion-between-faris-and-user697911).

Comment: BufferedWriter is more efficient ... but you are negating the efficiency by requiring the output to be written to the file "promptly".

Comment: @StephenC  I see.